# task scheduler in windows server 2008

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

The windows task scheduler fails to stop even after completing the task. It re-runs the completed task. So how to configure the task to stop after particular duration ??

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the task properly.

Comment: +1: AKA "You are doing it wrong."